# UA SDK Issues Compiling Server Application

Tags: c#, opc-ua, unified-automation-sdk

In regards to the following tutorial provided by Unified Automation for compiling an OPC UA server application:

[Compile Server Application](http://file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/UnifiedAutomation/UaModeler/doc/html/howgennetserver_sec.html)

The note in Step 1 directed me to the following task:

*First you have to remove the existing assemblies by choosing “Remove” from the context menu of the assembly. Then right-click on “References” in the solution explorer and choose “Add Reference”. Click on “Browse” to browse for the assemblies. The SDK installation directory contains a folder named “assemblies”, which itself contains several folders named “NET_[version]”. Add the assemblies located in the folder corresponding to the .NET framework you are using.*

When I attempted this, I could not find the assemblies it required me to browse for. I created the sample [project](http://file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/UnifiedAutomation/UaModeler/doc/html/howto_structureddatatypeandevents.html) that they used in exactly the same manner.

In short, the assemblies UnifiedAutomation.UaBase and UnifiedAutomation.UaServer  were missing from project and I could not add them. Also, System.Runtime.Serialization was missing as indicated by an exclamation point.

If you can offer me some guidance, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Have you installed  Unified Automation .NETSDK to the default path? Then assemblies should be there. Just do search in your folders for UaBase.

Comment: @Rekshino, I was able to find the assemblies. I now am able to run the server, but when I attempt to connect it to a client, I get a message "Could not connect too server: BadRequestHeaderInvalid". Do you know the source of this error and/or how to resolve it?

Comment: Wich protocol do you use? Do you connect via **opc.tcp:\\...**  or via http(s):\\ ?

Comment: @Rekshino I tried both and got that error each time

Comment: What setting do you have for security policy?

Comment: Is firewall off?

Comment: Actually you should ask another question, since you found answer for posted question. It would be good, if you post answer for other, who has same issue could find a solution.

Comment: What do you use as client?